# Autonomous Differential Equation $y' = (1 - \frac{A}{y})^{-1}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For an equation of the following form: $\frac{dy}{dt} = (1 - \frac{A}{y})^{-1}$ where $A > 0$ is a constant

Is there a way to solve for $y$ that doesn't involve using the Lambert $W$ function $($function such that $y = W(y)e^{W(y)})$?

When I go to solve this, I reach a stage with $\frac{y}{a} - \log(y) = \frac{t + c_1}{A}$ and I do not know of any ways to "isolate" the $y$ that don't involve the Lambert $W$ function.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha also expresses the solution in terms of the Lambert W function.

Comment: If you could solve this problem, you would have a formula for the Lambert $W$ function, wouldn't you?  So I don't see how you can avoid their use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Otherwise you would have found a way to circumvent Lambert's function with a closed-form expression, and you can bet that this would have been discovered since the XVIIIth Century.

Functions where the variable appears both inside and outside of a transcendental function have the habit of not being invertible analytically. Note that Lambert's function has countably many branches (in the complex), and this is enough to show that it has no algebraic expression.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful! I didn't know that trend about transcendental functions; thanks for including it in your answer, I'm glad to know :)

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = (1 - \frac{A}{y})^{-1}$$
$$(1 - \frac{A}{y})dy=dt$$
$$y-A\ln|y|=t+c$$
This is the solution on the form of implicit equation. Solving for $y$ cannot done with a finite number of elementary functions. It requires a special function namely the Lambert W function.

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html

Details of the calculus :

$$e^y y^{-A}=e^{t+c}$$
$$y^{A}e^{-y}=e^{-(t+c)}$$
$$ye^{-\frac{y}{A}}=e^{-\frac{t+c}{A}}$$
$$-\frac{y}{A}e^{-\frac{y}{A}}=-\frac{1}{A}e^{-\frac{t+c}{A}}$$
Let $X=-\frac{y}{A}$ and $Y=-\frac{1}{A}e^{-\frac{t+c}{A}}$
$$Xe^X=Y\quad\to\quad X=W(Y)$$
$W(X)$ is the Lambert W function.
$$-\frac{y}{A}=W\left(-\frac{1}{A}e^{-\frac{t+c}{A}}\right)$$
$$y=-A\:W\left(-\frac{1}{A}e^{-\frac{t+c}{A}}\right)$$